# File location is changed?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame, image

Using pygame (from pygame import *) I tried to load a picture, but this happened:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:/Users/Ben/Documents/Python Files/Rocket game with things", line 15, in <module>
 right_fin = image.load('C:\Users\Ben\Pictures\right.png').convert()
 error: Couldn't open C:\Users\Ben\Picturesight.png
```

There was basicly no code before this, so im not going to post it. I haven't encounted this before, nor have any idea what the problem even is. Sorry if the answer's obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backslashes have special meaning in Python strings, and `\r` is the escape code for a carriage return character.

Use double slashes, forward slashes or `r''` raw strings (which do *not* interpret backslashes as escape sequences) to define the path:

```
right_fin = image.load('C:\\Users\\Ben\\Pictures\\right.png').convert()
right_fin = image.load('C:/Users/Ben/Pictures/right.png').convert()
right_fin = image.load(r'C:\Users\Ben\Pictures\right.png').convert()
```